# A Matlab class for Commutative Hypercomplex number: How to overload the basic Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

I am programming **commutative hypercomplex number** class.

**First of all: If that already exist, please tell.** I have not found.
PS: Quaternion exists but are not commutative.

I am trying to reproduce all that Matlab can do with real and complex, but with hypercomplex. The solution that I am working on is to define a class. If a more smart method may be used, please tell.

Many codes with complex numbers exist, the idea is to overload smartly to make working all existing program with Hypercomplex. This work might be used by many users.

please see at the end of the post the main maths principle found in Ablamowicz1996 _ Clifford Algebras with Numeric and Symbolic Computations

My Hypercomplex class works for basic operation: I have overloaded the `mtimes(a,b) = a*b` operation.
For instance, I can do:

```
A = MyClass(1);
B = MyClass(2);
A*B; % ->that works
```

As a main problem, for instance in 2D, I would like to be able to use

```
[A B C].*[D ; E]
```

while using the element-wise behavior of Matlab, and for any dimension , and with my definition of `*`. For instance, while dealing with matrices of compatible size but not identical:

```
A = [1 2 3]; B = [1;2]
```

Matlab gives

```
A.*B    
ans =

 1     2     3
 2     4     6
```

That works also for N dimension when compatible.
How can I overload `times(a,b) = a.*b` , power, rdivide.. in order to have the element-wise behavior of Matlab?

Here is my Class

```
classdef Hypercomplex < handle
    properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public)
        A
    end
    properties (SetAccess = private, GetAccess = private)
        eps,nu,e1,e2
    end
    
    methods
        function s = Hypercomplex(Z)             %% Conctruc
            % Z might be real, complex or hypercomplex
            if isa(Z,'Hypercomplex')            % is HyperComplex
                s = Z;
            elseif ~isreal(Z) && length(Z) == 1 % is Complex
                s = Hypercomplex([real(Z) imag(Z) 0 0]);
            elseif isreal(Z) && length(Z) < 5
                s.A = zeros(1,4);
                for ii = 1:length(Z)            % is vecteur
                    s.A(ii) = Z(ii);
                end
            end
        end
        function s = epsnu(s)
            s.eps = (s.A(1) - s.A(4)) + 1i*(s.A(2)+s.A(3));
            s.nu  = (s.A(1) + s.A(4)) + 1i*(s.A(2)-s.A(3));
        end
        function s = e1e2(s)
            s.e1 = Hypercomplex([0.5 0 0 -0.5]);
            s.e2 = Hypercomplex([0.5 0 0  0.5]);
        end
        %% Overload
        function out = cos(a)
            a.epsnu.e1e2;
            out = cos(a.eps)*a.e1 + cos(a.nu)*a.e2;
            % I might also do for  sin exp sqrt ...
        end
        
        function out = mtimes(a,b) % '*'
            a = Hypercomplex(a).epsnu;
            b = Hypercomplex(b).epsnu;
            eps12 = 0.5*(a.eps * b.eps);% produit complex
            nu12  = 0.5*(a.nu  * b.nu );% produit complex
            
            h1 = Hypercomplex([real(eps12) imag(eps12) imag(eps12) -real(eps12)]);
            h2 = Hypercomplex([real(nu12)  imag(nu12) -imag(nu12)   real(nu12) ]);
            out = h1+h2;
        end
        function out = mrdivide(a,b)
            a = Hypercomplex(a);
            b = Hypercomplex(b);
            out = a * b.inverse;
        end
        function s = inverse(s)
            s = Hypercomplex(s).epsnu.e1e2;
            s = 1/(s.eps)*s.e1 + 1/(s.nu)*s.e2;
        end
        function out = plus(a,b)
            a = Hypercomplex(a);
            b = Hypercomplex(b);
            out = Hypercomplex(a.A + b.A);
        end
        function out = minus(a,b)
            a = Hypercomplex(a);
            b = Hypercomplex(b);
            out = Hypercomplex(a.A - b.A);
        end
    end
end
```

Example i^2 = -1 :

```
>> Ni =  Hypercomplex([0 1 0 0]) ;
>> Ni*Ni
  Hypercomplex with properties:

    A: [-1 0 0 0]
```

[image: Principle of cimmutative hypercomplex]

Comment: You likely need to overload `times` to use `bsxfun` (the way implicit expansion was done before it was a native functionality) with your overloaded `mtimes`

Comment: I have tried bsxfun(@mtimes,A,B) but A and B needs to be numeric Array, and not from the Class I have define. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think if they were of your defined class then the overload would work, no?

Comment: Apparently, it does not work, even if applied inside of the call

Answer (score 1):

I would think you need to loop over your arrays, and have a special case where, if for one dimension one of the inputs has size 1 and the other doesn't, then the same element for that array is used. A simple way to accomplish this is to index with `(i-1)*step + 1`, where `step` is 0 if the array has size 1, and 1 otherwise.

One thing to note is that, in your overloaded method, indexing doesn't use your custom indexing definition (`subsref` and `subsasgn`), but the built-in one.

For example, assuming you only allow 2D arrays of your class:

```matlab
function C = times(A, B)
szA = size(A);
szB = size(B);
if numel(szA)~=2 || numel(szB)~=2
   error('Only 2D arrays are supported')
end
szC = max(szA, szB);
stepA = [matchSizes(szA(1), szC(1)), matchSizes(szA(2), szC(2))];
stepB = [matchSizes(szB(1), szC(1)), matchSizes(szB(2), szC(2))];
C = MyClass.empty(szC);
for jj = 1:szC(2)
   for ii = 1:szC(1)
      C(ii,jj) = A((ii-1)*stepA(1)+1,(jj-1)*stepA(2)+1) * B((ii-1)*stepB(1)+1,(jj-1)*stepB(2)+1);
   end
end

% private helper function, keep in the same file
function step = matchSizes(szIn, szOut)
step = 1;
if szIn ~= szOut
   if szIn == 1
      step = 0;
   else
      error('Sizes not compatible')
   end
end
```

NOTE: Code not tested.

NOTE2: This is one of the cases where 0-based indexing is more convenient!

Comment: That works well, brillant Cris. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyClass` has a property `val` to store numeric values I think (hope) that this should be possible (not tested):

```
function obj = times(A, B)
  r = reshape([A.val], size(A)) .* reshape([B.val], size(B));
  obj = arrayfun(@MyClass, r);
end
```

EDIT (because question is edited):

You can follow two ways to implement array of those numbers:

1. Array of objects
   In this method each object just contains a hypercomplex number. It is the way that you have tried. As @CrisLuengo pointed out you can use loops to create the desired result or you can use a combination of vectorization and use of functions like `arrayfun` and `cellfun`. You need to know how to work with cell arrays and comma separated list and be familiar with verctorization operations like implicit expansion. Here I implemented `plus` and `epsnu` using vectorization and `cellfun`. They can work with both scalar and object arrays:

   ```
    function out = plus(a,b)
        a = Hypercomplex(a);
        b = Hypercomplex(b);
        AA = reshape([a.A], [4, size(a)]);
        BB = reshape([b.A], [4, size(b)]])
        CC = AA + BB;
        A1 = reshape()
        out = cellfun(@Hypercomplex, num2cell(reshape(CC, 4, []).', 2));
    end 

    function s = epsnu(s)
      AA = reshape([s.A], 4, []);
      eps = num2cell(AA(1, :) - AA(4, :) + 1i.*(AA(2, :) + AA(3, :)));
      nu = num2cell(AA(1, :) + AA(4, :) + 1i.*(AA(2, :) - AA(3, :)));
      [s.eps] = eps{:};
      [s.nu] = nu{:};
   end
   ```
2. Object containing array of numbers
   Instead of defining `A` as a `[4 x 1]` array you can define each coordinate `(x,y,z,et)` as a separate property of class each can contain array of numbers. you need to overload the `cat` operator to concatenate objects. As a result no object array is created but the underlying verctors are concatenated. You need tooverload `subsref` and `subsasgn` if you want to simulate element access. I think this method is simpler to implement than the first method.

Comment: A.val is is 4x1 vector with [1 i j k]. Indeed, I am trying to create an commutative HyperComplex number class. I think my question was not complete enough, I am about to post a new question with more details.

Comment: You can edit the current question.

Comment: So as I understand the class gets a real scalar and forms a hypercomplex number?

Comment: Ok, i will re -edit: Is there a way to share the MyClass.m file to be more specific?

Comment: Here you yneed to provide a minimal working example. Just copy/patse a simplified version to your edit.

Comment: thanks -  I ll try the second option.